# Fill Rect to pdf php into F or D

Tags: php, pdf

i want to ask how to output rect on pdf.php. the values is F or D based on user input

for example i have form that ask gender. if user choose male then the D is become F

```
$pdf->Rect(126, 35.5, 3, 3, 'D', array('all' => $gariskecil));
```

and when the user choose female the second rect becomes F

```
$pdf->Rect(136, 35.5, 3, 3, 'D', array('all' => $gariskecil));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set gender via js event listener, jquery or php form

for example with php post method form

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
```

then apply it to your fpdf

```
$pdf->Rect(136, 35.5, 3, 3, $gender, array('all' => $gariskecil));
```